# Advice for feeding a scratching, overweight cat

Tags: cats, feeding, weight, scratching

My grandma's cat has gotten rather overweight in recent years. Thankfully she's still an active cat, but that increasing rotundness does not look healthy.

My grandma told me that she can't really feed the cat less, because when she tried, the cat cried and scratched her. (This is normally a well-behaved, quiet, if very shy cat. Follows my grandma everywhere).

What I assume makes things difficult is that the cat won't eat wet cat food. It also does not like kibble mixed with water. So its normal meals are dried cat food, and with some fish/meat scraps from the kitchen on the side (has a water bowl).

Would you have advice?

I've seen 'Tiger Diner' cat bowls mentioned in a related post (https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/138/25460) . I'm happy to get one. Just wanted to check more thoughts, especially since the previous question did not mention scratching.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! How does the cat scratch your grandma? Is it coming over to her to do so? Or happens it at the food bowl? Before or after eating?

Comment: @Allerleirauh Thank you...Welp, I called my grandma to double-check and apparently the scratching incident was unrelated to the feeding and probably play behaviour. Which is entirely different from what she told me yesterday. Can only suspect grandma didn't want to outright admit she's overfeeding the cat. As that entirely changes the premise of the question, I'd appreciate if this could be closed. I will use existing advice on overweight cats (e.g. Tiger Diner, feeder toy) and hope that they work well enough that both the cat and the cat's main person are collaborating...

Comment: You are welcome :) If you have a follow up question, or other questions, feel free to start a new one. I will vote to close this question, this will start the process to close it. But you can too make this decision and delete it yourself. Wish you, grandma and the cat all the best :)

Comment: i just want you to know that old experienced female cats are the most stubborn animals on our planet so you will need help from everybody that feeds the cat,your vet can give you advice about how to make the cat loose weight.